# How to read an Object in a Bucket with pluses and spaces in its name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've set up an event handler on a Bucket (in AWS). The event handler is supposed to read the file and process it. And I have a problem with the files that have *space* in their filename.

When I upload a file with name `+ .txt`, on the event handler I receive `++.txt`. I understand that *spaces* are replaced with `+` but how can I differentiate between *spaces* and actual *pluses*? How can I read such a file on the event handler?

Comment: simply by not uploading the file with + and space in its name.

Comment: @Asdfg I'm not the one who uploads the files and I can't be sure that the user will comply with such restrictions!

Comment: sure they can if you ask them nicely. :)

Comment: Only if! :) :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 treats `+` and `%20` **identically**.  They are both represented internally as `+`.  There is no differentiation.  An unescaped space in a URI is a protocol violation, so your original upload must have had `%20` for the space.

`foo+bar` and `foo%20bar` refer to exactly the same object, whose key is `foo bar`.

To get the correct object key from an event, you need this:

```
const real_key = decodeURIComponent(event.s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
```

This is the result of a very old bug in S3, and the current incorrect behavior is too entrenched in existing libraries to allow it to be fixed without widespread collateral damage.

Note also that `%2B` is *not* considered equivalent to `+` by S3, but since browsers don't eacape URLs that way, storing objects with `%2B` in the key does not interoperate well.